# how do I call a constructor from a class loaded at runtime? Java

Tags: java, constructor, classloader, nosuchmethoderror, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a class loader that loads the "main" class from all jar files in the /plugins folder
this assumes that all jars have the package plugin.(plugin name) containing the class called main.  each main class has a constructor called main.

the classes load successfully, but I need to know how to call the main constructor from the loaded class.

(this class/classes are loaded at runtime)

I have tried using this:

```
Constructor c = cls.getConstructor(Integer.class); //line 41

Plugin plug = (Plugin) c.newInstance(0);
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: plugin.myplugin.main.<init>(java.lang.Integer)  
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)  
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)  
at hkr.classloader.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:41)  
at hkr.core.startup.InitializeGame.inigame(InitializeGame.java:32)  
at hkr.launcher.main.LauncherMain.main(LauncherMain.java:16)  

package hackers.classloader;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import org.java.plugin.Plugin;

public class PluginLoader 
{
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "rawtypes", "resource" })
    public static void loadPlugins() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        Class cls = null;
        int x = hackers.core.startup.InitializeGame.map.size();
        for (int i = 1; i<=x;i++)
        {
            String className = hackers.core.startup.InitializeGame.map.get(i + "");

            File file  = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "plugins" + File.separator + className + ".jar");
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = file.toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

            try {
                cls = cl.loadClass("plugin." + className + ".main");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Constructor c = cls.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE);
            Plugin plug = (Plugin) c.newInstance(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is cls and does it have a Integer (not int) constructor?

Comment: (You're better off using `Class.asSubclass`, rather than doing the cast after construction.)

Comment: Is the constructor public? If not, try using `cls.getDeclaredConstructor(Integer.class)`.

Comment: Is there a constructor with parameter Integer? There is int.class for an int parameter. Otherwise do `getConstructor()`. Just like `cls.getDeclaredMethod(String[].class)` as it is `main(String[])`.

Comment: This doesn't address your problem, but the classes should be called `Main` not `main`.  All class names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Further to @StephenC 's comment, main is usually reserved by convention to be the static entry point into a class to be run.  Calling your class "main" and using a constructor called "main" will add complexity to understanding your code, unless it was intentionally chosen for precisely that purpose.

Comment: "main" is just temporary until I get this working, from there it wont be hard to change

Comment: @user1718720 - Why don't you just fix it now?  Seriously, if you ask other people questions about code that violates coding standards and conventions, then it wastes **their** time due to the misunderstandings it causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your constructor takes an `java.lang.Integer`, from what I see, your code should work.

But if your constructor's sole parameter is an `int`, `getConstructor` will fail. You have to use Integer.TYPE instead of Integer.class in that case.
I I am right, what you need to do is:

```
Constructor c = cls.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE);
```

Edit: Based on your edits and your comments, there are several problems.

1. The class you want to load does not seem to have any explicit constructor, which means that you simply need to do `cls.getConstructor()`
2. What you want to execute (`public static void main`), is a static method for which you normally don't need an instance of a class. Also, I'm not sure "main" would be a good name for the reasons explained by user @Eric B.
3. Since you want to call a method, You have to instantiate the constructor AND also call the method.

Based on my understanding, the code you would want to execute should be something like that:

```
Constructor c = cls.getConstructor(); // we get the implicit constructor without parameters
Plugin plugin = (Plugin) c.newInstance(); // we instantiate it, no parameters

Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", Integer.TYPE);
m.invoke(plugin, 0); // we invoke the method "main" on our dynamically loaded class, with the 0 parameter.
```

Comment: it makes a : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: plugin.myplugin.main.<init>(int)

Comment: is the constructor public ? If not you have to use getDeclaredConstructor instead of getConstructor

Comment: and the constructor being calles is:    public static void main(int a)
 {
  System.out.println("PLUGIN LOADED!");
 } - which is temporary

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: plugin.myplugin.main cannot be cast to org.java.plugin.Plugin
 at hackers.classloader.PluginLoader.loadPlugins(PluginLoader.java:43)
 at hackers.core.startup.InitializeGame.inigame(InitializeGame.java:32)
 at hackers.launcher.main.LauncherMain.main(LauncherMain.java:16)

Comment: I think its saying that c.newInstance() cant be cast as (Plugin) but I dont know what else to cast it as.  also the int can be removed it was there because the old method i was attempting would search for a constructor that has the parameter of int to determine what constructor to call.  the constructor never actually uses that int, it was just there for finding the constructor

Comment: Do you work with an IDE such as NetBeans, or Eclipse ? I think you should go in debug mode and stop at a breakpoint before the newInstance call. You will then be able to check on the debugger what is the class that has been loaded.